# Providing two combined Reducers for my redux saga store prevents my websocket channel message from triggering, but only one does not?

Tags: websocket, next.js, reduce, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

**Configured my store this way with redux toolkit for sure**

```
  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
      someReducer,
      systemsConfigs
      });

  const store = return configureStore({
      devTools: true,
      reducer: rootReducer ,
      // middleware: [middleware, logger],
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({ thunk: false }).concat(middleware),
 
    });
  middleware.run(sagaRoot)
```

**And thats my channel i am connecting to it**

```
export function createSocketChannel(
  productId: ProductId,
  pair: string,
  createSocket = () => new WebSocket('wss://somewebsocket')
) {
  return eventChannel<SocketEvent>((emitter) => {
    const socket_OrderBook = createSocket();
    socket_OrderBook.addEventListener('open', () => {
      emitter({
        type: 'connection-established',
        payload: true,
      });
      
      socket_OrderBook.send(
        `subscribe-asdqwe`
      );
    });

    socket_OrderBook.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      if (event.data?.includes('bids')) {
        emitter({
          type: 'message',
          payload: JSON.parse(event.data),
        });
        //
      }
    });

    socket_OrderBook.addEventListener('close', (event: any) => {
      emitter(new SocketClosedByServer());
    });
    return () => {
      if (socket_OrderBook.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        socket_OrderBook.send(
          `unsubscribe-order-book-${pair}`
        );
      }
      if (socket_OrderBook.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN || socket_OrderBook.readyState === WebSocket.CONNECTING) {
        socket_OrderBook.close();
      }
    };
  }, buffers.expanding<SocketEvent>());
}
```

**And here's how my saga connecting handlers looks like**

```
export function* handleConnectingSocket(ctx: SagaContext) {
  try {
    const productId = yield select((state: State) => state.productId);
    const requested_pair = yield select((state: State) => state.requested_pair);

    if (ctx.socketChannel === null) {
      ctx.socketChannel = yield call(createSocketChannel, productId, requested_pair);
    }
    //
    const message: SocketEvent = yield take(ctx.socketChannel!);

    if (message.type !== 'connection-established') {
      throw new SocketUnexpectedResponseError();
    }

    yield put(connectedSocket());
  } catch (error: any) {
    reportError(error);

    yield put(
      disconnectedSocket({
        reason: SocketStateReasons.BAD_CONNECTION,
      })
    );
  }
}

export function* handleConnectedSocket(ctx: SagaContext) {
  try {
    while (true) {
      if (ctx.socketChannel === null) {
        break;
      }

      const events = yield flush(ctx.socketChannel);

      const startedExecutingAt = performance.now();

      if (Array.isArray(events)) {
        const deltas = events.reduce(
          (patch, event) => {
            if (event.type === 'message') {
              patch.bids.push(...event.payload.data?.bids);
              patch.asks.push(...event.payload.data?.asks);
              //
            }
            //

            return patch;
          },
          { bids: [], asks: [] } as SocketMessage
        );

        if (deltas.bids.length || deltas.asks.length) {
          yield putResolve(receivedDeltas(deltas));
        }
      }

      yield call(delayNextDispatch, startedExecutingAt);
    }
  } catch (error: any) {
    reportError(error);

    yield put(
      disconnectedSocket({
        reason: SocketStateReasons.UNKNOWN,
      })
    );
  }
}
```

After Debugging I got the following:

The Thing is that when I Provide one Reducer to my store the channel works well and data is fetched where as when providing combinedReducers I am getting

***an established connection from my handleConnectingSocket generator function***

and an empty event array [] from

***const events = yield flush(ctx.socketChannel) written in handleConnectedSocket***

Tried to clarify as much as possible

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

ok so I start refactoring my typescript by changing the types, then saw all the places that break, there was a problem in my sagas.tsx.

Ping me if someone faced such an issue in the future